# Configure a custom AuthenticationFailureHandler using Java configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

How can I configure a custom `AuthenticationFailureHandler` in Spring Security using Java-based configuration? I already have a `SecurityConfig` class which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and configures HTTP Basic Authentication using httpBasic(), but I can't figure out how to set the `AuthenticationFailureHandler`.

My real goal is to redirect to an external URL (login page) instead of returning a 401 response for some requests only (GET requests to certain URLs), so if there's another or better way to do that I'd like to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass it in failureHandler method.. chain can looks like this:

```
http.formLogin().failureHandler()
```

Seems that class provided by spring can help you with simple redirect:

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks freakman, and your answer is correct for formLogin() so I'm giving you an up-vote. Unfortunately, I didn't mention that I'm actually using HTTP Basic Authentication using httpBasic(). Really sorry for not mentioning that before. I will update my question.

Comment: not tried that before.. but take a look at http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint). AuthEntryPoint example is BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint class - it's commence method returns unathorized http response. You can try to provide your class and use sendRedirect method from HttpServletResponse.

Answer (score 2):

I used freakman's suggestion of creating a custom BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint class. Here is my code in case anyone else needs to do something similar:

```
// See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/3.2.x/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint.java
public class CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {
    private static Logger logger = loggerFactory.getLogger(CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);

    @Value("${crm.integration.sso.login.form.url}")
    private String loginFormUrl;

    /**
     * This method is called when authentication fails.
     */
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String path = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length());
        logger.info(String.format("CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence() - %s", path));
        if ("GET".equals(request.getMethod().toUpperCase())
                && path.startsWith("/manage")
        ) {
            response.sendRedirect(loginFormUrl);
        } else {
            super.commence(request, response, authException);
        }
    }

}
```